# Electron forge + webpack + ts + dugite: Git was not found

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, electron

I am running an Electron app based on the electron forge template ([available here](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template)). In the webpack.main.config.ts file, I added the following lines as suggested [here](https://github.com/desktop/dugite/issues/96):

```
node: {
    __dirname: true,
  },
```

When I run `npm start`, it works perfectly. However, when I build it (`npm run build`), the main process crashes. When I inspect it, I get the same error: dugite is trying to reach for "git" inside the "node_modules" folder of my packaged app... Which doesn't exist!

[image: Error from attached debugger]

I would love to get some help!

Thank you very much!